# How to check if cell is empty before checking if statement is true or false in excel?

Tags: excel, cells

I have this formula (an example):

```
=OR(H46/B46-1>SUVProgress,I46/C46-1>S
UVProgress,J46/D46-1>SUVProgress,K46/E46-1>SUVProgress,L46/F46-1>SUVProgress)
```

SUVProgress is defined as 30% on another sheet.
As of now, it compares 2 sets of 5 cells and returns the value true if the value is greater than SUVProgress. It has to look at all 5 cells, but what happens if that cell is empty.  As of now, it returns a #DIV/0! because not all the cells are filled with a value.

What I don't know how to do is how to check if there's empty cells. Some of the data only have 2 sets of 3 cells filled as opposed to the entire 5.

How would I re-write the formula to only do the operation for only the cells that have values in them?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the portion of the formulae should return FALSE for an empty cell, you could try to surround each of the operands of the OR with IFERROR(..., FALSE), like so:

`=OR(IFERROR(H46/B46-1>SUVProgress, FALSE), IFERROR(I46/C46-1>SUVProgress, FALSE),IFERROR(J46/D46-1>SUVProgress, FALSE),IFERROR(K46/E46-1>SUVProgress< FALSE),IFERROR(L46/F46-1>SUVProgress, FALSE))`

The effect should be that those portions contribute a FALSE, in case there is an (=any) error in that portion of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you can use an `=IF(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false)` function to check if the cells are empty.